# CSS and basic HTML functions like link don't work after translation

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a multilingual page right now. I managed to translate the content but as soon as you hit the language button all the CSS disappears. The links are not functioning after the translation as well. So basically after the translation no CSS and no HTML seems to be working properly.

I provided a JS Fiddle below.

https://jsfiddle.net/a5frtm1j/

How can I solve this?

```css
.nav{
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #105ea6;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;

    
}
    
nav ul{
    color: #105ea6;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 25px;

}
nav ul li a{
    color: #105ea6;
    display:inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    border: 2px grey solid;
    width: 250px;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    cursor: pointer;


}
nav ul li a:hover{
    border: 2px grey solid;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 250px;
    background-color: #105ea6;
    color: #f4f4f4;
    border-radius: 8px;
}
.header_navbar{
    font-size: x-large;
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 40px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
    <div id="content">
        <img src="IMAGES_AYNU/elsner_logo1.svg" width="150" height="150"/>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <body>
        <head>
            <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/9cef10a72a.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Hauptmenü</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS_AYNU/AYNU.Style.css">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var arrLang = {
      'en': {
        'wateringzones': 'Wateringzones',
        'sensors': 'Sensors',
        'back': 'Back',
        'mainmenue': 'Main menu',
        'help': 'Help'
      },
      'de': {
        'wateringzones': 'Bewässerungszonen',
        'sensors': 'Sensoren',
        'back': 'Zurück',
        'mainmenue':'Hauptmenü',
        'help': 'Hilfe'
      }
    };

    // Process translation
    $(function() {
      $('.translate').click(function() {
        var lang = $(this).attr('id');

        $('.lang').each(function(index, item) {
          $(this).text(arrLang[lang][$(this).attr('key')]);
        });
      });
    });
  </script>
        </head>
        <div class="header_navbar">
            <header>
                <button id="en" class="translate">English</button>
                <button id="de" class="translate">Deutsch</button>
                <br>
                <h1 class="lang" key="mainmenue">Hauptmenü  <i class="fas fa-bars"></i></h1>
                    
            </header>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="navebar">
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li class="navbar lang" key="wateringzones"><a href="AYNU_WATERINGZONES.html">Bewässerungszonen</a></li>
                    <br>
                    <li class="navbar lang" key="sensors"><a href="AYNU_SENSORS.html">Sensoren</a></li>
                    <br>
                    <li class="navbar lang" key="back"><a href="AYNU.Structure.html">Zurück</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <br>
        <br>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You `lang` class is on `li` element, it mean your change whole `li` including your `<a>` element

Comment: Thank you, everything works fine again!

Comment: glad to hear that :)

Answer (score 0):

You `lang` class is on `li` element, its mean you will change whole `li` including your  element when translate it, move your `key` attribute and `lang` class to `<a>`.

btw: your `head` tag is misplaced, use head in the top of your `body` tag not inside it.

```css
.nav{
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #105ea6;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
    
nav ul{
    color: #105ea6;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 25px;
}
nav ul li a{
    color: #105ea6;
    display:inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    border: 2px grey solid;
    width: 250px;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
nav ul li a:hover{
    border: 2px grey solid;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 250px;
    background-color: #105ea6;
    color: #f4f4f4;
    border-radius: 8px;
}
.header_navbar{
    font-size: x-large;
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 40px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
    <head>
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/9cef10a72a.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Hauptmenü</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS_AYNU/AYNU.Style.css">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var arrLang = {
                'en': {
                    'wateringzones': 'Wateringzones',
                    'sensors': 'Sensors',
                    'back': 'Back',
                    'mainmenue': 'Main menu',
                    'help': 'Help'
                },
                'de': {
                    'wateringzones': 'Bewässerungszonen',
                    'sensors': 'Sensoren',
                    'back': 'Zurück',
                    'mainmenue':'Hauptmenü',
                    'help': 'Hilfe'
                }
            };

            // Process translation
            $(function() {
            $('.translate').click(function() {
                var lang = $(this).attr('id');

                $('.lang').each(function(index, item) {
                $(this).text(arrLang[lang][$(this).attr('key')]);
                });
            });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
        
    <body>
        <div class="header_navbar">
            <header>
                <button id="en" class="translate">English</button>
                <button id="de" class="translate">Deutsch</button>
                <br>
                <h1 class="lang" key="mainmenue">Hauptmenü  <i class="fas fa-bars"></i></h1>
                    
            </header>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="navebar">
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li class="navbar"><a class="lang" key="wateringzones" href="AYNU_WATERINGZONES.html">Bewässerungszonen</a></li>
                    <br>
                    <li class="navbar"><a class="lang" key="sensors" href="AYNU_SENSORS.html">Sensoren</a></li>
                    <br>
                    <li class="navbar"><a class="lang" key="back" href="AYNU.Structure.html">Zurück</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <br>
        <br>
    </body>
</html>
```